# Self-answered question where the problem came from a framework; should I put a link to the opened GitHub issues?

Tags: discussion, answers

Basically, the other day, I asked a question on Stack Overflow about an unusual behaviour when coding in TypeScript using Angular.

After a few days of searching deeper, I realised the problem came from Angular itself, so I decided to self-answer my question, by giving the steps to reproduce (and the steps to make it work), after which I went on GitHub and opened an issue on the Angular/Angular CLI project.

Should I include the links to the opened issues in my answer, or isn't it necessary?

Comment: It's up to you. Links to official or non-official resources which *improve* your answer are generally appreciated. I'd say the link to the github issue is likely helpful here.

Comment: Any information that add's to the answer should be included, you want the answer to be as detailed as possible to give it the best chance of helping others.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, add a link to the official issue tracking. Make sure the answer itself contains enough information about the issue and not just a link-only post, "see official issue 12345".

In addition to providing more information this will let other people to maintain the Q/A pair in the future. If the issue is eventually resolved anyone else can see that and update/add an answer with "Issue fixed in version X.Y.Z. You need to ... ".

Comment: And for Apple-related issues, please link to an https://openradar.appspot.com, which is **UN**official, but is the only public way to link to Apple issues.